# How to get the next element to the current in a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I have the LinkedHashMap with some unknown data inside.

```
//==================
Map< Integer, String > map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put(10, "C");
map.put(20, "C++");
map.put(50, "JAVA");
map.put(40, "PHP");
map.put(30, "Kotlin");
//=============
```

And I know just the key = 50;

I am wondering what is the best way to get the next element to the element that I have by this key (50)? This is not a multi-threaded application. I don't worry about thread-safety.

I don't like the way to iterate all keys through entrySet from the beginning.

It would be great to somehow get access to the `next()` of `LinkedHashMap`s Entry.

Comment: Unfortunately this/default implementation doesn't expose "it's links" (all private/protected)...https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f3ca0cab75f2faf9ec88f7a380490c9589a27102/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#L568

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Answer (score 1):

This is `LinkedHashMap` so it remembers the order of elements insertion.

```java
public static Map.Entry<Integer, String> getNextEntry(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map, Integer key) {
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    int index = keys.indexOf(key);

    if (index < 0 || index >= keys.size() - 1)
        return null;

    int k = keys.get(index + 1);
    return Map.entry(k, map.get(k));
}
```

Or you can use `Iterator`:

```java
public static Map.Entry<Integer, String> getNextEntry(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map, Integer key) {
    boolean found = false;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (found)
            return Map.entry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        if (entry.getKey().intValue() == key)
            found = true;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Look like it is a best option available. Of course it is an additional duplication memory with ArrayLIst

Comment: @user20301714 Keep in mind that there's ather option apart from iterating through the Entry Set, if you're using `LinkedHashMap`. You can only hide the actual process of iteration, [that's what `indexOf()` does](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l295). And dumping the entries into the list unnecessarily increases the **memory consumption**, hence characteristic "the best" is doubtful.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashMap` **doesn't** offer a functionality which would allow finding the next *key* or *entry*.

In case if you simply don't want to bother with managing iteration yourself manually, then sure you can alternate this process, but keep in mind that the iteration should happen somewhere anyway.

## Stream API

Alternatively you can make use of the Stream API if you don't want to bother with loops.

```
public static Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> getNextEntry(Map<Integer, String> map,
                                                                int previous) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .dropWhile(entry -> entry.getKey() != previous) // discard the entries, until the target key has been encountered
        .skip(1)      // skip the entry with the target key
        .findFirst(); // grab the next entry and return it as an Optional (because the next entry might not exist)
}
```

## TreeMap

However, you would be able to navigate through the *keys* of the map if you were using a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

`TreeMap` maintains a red-black tree under the hood, and it keep the *entries* in sorted order based on *keys*. And it offers various method like `higherEntry()`, `higherKey()`.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

// populating the map
    
int key = 50;
    
Map.Entry<Integer, String> next = map.higherEntry(key);
```

Comment: Thank you but TreeMap is a map implementation that keeps its entries sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys But I need the order of elements insertion.

Comment: @user20301714 If you want to bother with loops, I've added another option (see the update).

Comment: what I'm really looking for is the best way to find a complete or partial match of all elements of a LinkedHashMap. To do this, I need a quick search using hash and a selection of subsequent ones from the found element.

Comment: @user20301714 Have a look at the source code of the `LinkedHashMap` and see for yourself what's it capable of, and what it's not (I've already provided you with the link). Several people, including [Guava library author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74254800/how-to-get-the-next-element-to-the-current-in-a-linkedhashmap/74254936?noredirect=1#comment131097289_74254800), have already told you that it's not possible. Also, "partial match" with retrieving a *value* by *key*.

Comment: @user20301714 Theoretically, you can create your **custom** Linked Hash Map implementation **from scratch**, which would be capable to retrieve the *next key*, or the *next entry* in amortized constant time **O(1)**. But it's a huge piece of work.